# How do I set UITableViewCell background while maintaining rounded corners?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am setting the contentView.backgroundColor on a UITableViewCell.

```
UIColor *tracingColor = [self getColourFromResult: [[NSString alloc] initWithString: model.traceResultString]];
tracingResultCell.contentView.backgroundColor = tracingColor;
```

The first row in the TableViewCellSection loses its rounded corners when doing this. Weirdly if you look closely as i've set the background color opacity to 0.70 you can actually see the rounded corners through the background (image below).

The end row maintains the rounded corners though.

How do I maintain the first row rounded corners?

[image: image screenshot]

Comment: It is used by QuartZCore framework

Comment: Why did you trying to set back ground color to content-view? backgroundcolor property is available to tableviewcells.  tracingResultCell.backgroundColor = tracingColor;

Comment: This is the answer (i obviously just used the wrong property for the top cell). Write this as an answer and i'll mark it for you :)